# DropDownList won't load

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-10

I have an ASP.NET Web Application that has a dropdownlist which pulls up student records.  This works on all browsers, Android OS and IOS except for the new IE on the windows tablet.  Does anyone know why it's not loading or pulling the information?

Here's some code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"  DataTextField="zName" DataValueField="Id" 
        AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString1 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Id, (lName + ', ' + fName) AS zName FROM bleaTest"></asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<ItemTemplate>
            <span class="style1">Id:
            <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" CssClass="bold" 
                Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>' />
            <br />
            First Name:
            <asp:Label ID="fNameLabel" runat="server" CssClass="bold" 
                Text='<%# Bind("fName") %>' />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Last Name:
            <asp:Label ID="lNameLabel" runat="server" CssClass="bold" 
                Text='<%# Bind("lName") %>' />
            &nbsp;<br /> Gender:
            <asp:Label ID="genLabel" runat="server" CssClass="bold" 
                Text='<%# Bind("gen") %>' />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Agency:
            <asp:Label ID="agencyLabel" runat="server" CssClass="bold" 
                Text='<%# Bind("agency") %>' />
            <br />
            Title:
            <asp:Label ID="titleLabel" runat="server" CssClass="bold" 
                Text='<%# Bind("title") %>' />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </span>
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString1 %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [bleaTest] WHERE [Id] = @Id" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Id, fName, lName, agency, title, gen, hired, AppS, course, Location, SessNum, SDate, EDate, Hours, SitUps, pushUps, rTime, Grade FROM bleaTest WHERE (Id = @Id)"


        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [bleaTest] SET [fName] = @fName, [lName] = @lName, [agency] = @agency, [title] = @title, [gen] = @gen, [hired] = @hired, [AppS] = @Apps, [course] = @course, [Location] = @Location, [SDate] = @SDate, [EDate] = @EDate, [Hours] = @Hours WHERE [Id] = @Id">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <SelectParameters> 
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Id"  
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" /> 

        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="fName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="lName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Agency" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="title" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="gen" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="hired" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Apps" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="course" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Location" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="EDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Hours" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Gonna need a bit more info than that... show some code, what have you tried, are there errors, etc...

Comment: No real errors, just when I click on a students name nothing seems to load, sorry I'll provide more code.  Like I said it works on all browsers on my PC, Android, IOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some more research and figured it out (Finally).  For some reason or maybe a security reason, IE10 has an issue with doing a `postback`  I found a great link that might help some people out.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Hope this helps!